# When is swap triggered or how to calculate swap_tendency?

Tags: linux, kernel, swap, meminfo

I'm trying to use Redis for production services and trying to avoiding swapping, which is bad for performance.

I had learn that swap is triggered by swap_tendency which is depending on

> swap_tendency = mapped_ratio/2 + swappiness + distress

How can I get mapped_ratio/distress from `/proc/meminfo` for my monitor script?

Or anything parameter that can info me that system is going to swap pages?

Comment: Might be useful to answering this: http://www.linuxvox.com/2009/10/what-is-the-linux-kernel-parameter-vm-swappiness/

Comment: This URL discusses the mapped_ratio a bit: https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l19.pdf

Comment: Maybe also this [Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32333/44370).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### mapped_ratio

`mapped_ratio` can be calculated like so:

```
mapped ratio = (nr mapped * 100) / total memory;
```

*Source: https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l19.pdf*

#### nr_mapped

The value, `nr_mapped` can be read from `/proc/vmstat`:

```
$ grep nr_mapped /proc/vmstat
nr_mapped 47640
```

#### distress

According to this article, titled: [Linux Memory - Implementation Notes](http://davesmisc.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/linux-memory/)

> “This is a measurement of how much difficulty the VM is having reclaiming pages. Each time the VM tries to reclaim memory, it scans 1/nth of the inactive lists in each zone in an effort to reclaim pages. Each time a pass over the list is made, if the number of inactive clean + free pages in that zone is not over the low water mark, n is decreased by one. Distress is measured as 100 >> n” [5](http://www.linuxvox.com/2009/10/what-is-the-linux-kernel-parameter-vm-swappiness/)

In researching much of the docs make it sounds as though "distress" is a kernel counter but it is not. Rather it's a value that's used when each zone of memory is being scanned, that is progressively increased as page frames of memory are scanned by the kernel in an attempt to reclaim them. Discussion of this is beyond the scope of this Q&A but if you're curious the section of the book "Understanding the Linux Kernel", [Chapter 17: Page Frame Reclaiming](http://idak.gop.edu.tr/esmeray/UnderStandingKernel.pdf). The value of "distress" comes from the value "prev_priority" as the zones are scanned.

#### References

- [Understanding Memory](http://careers.directi.com/display/tu/Understanding+and+optimizing+Memory+utilization)
- [Linux Memory Allocation - PDF](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/l19.pdf)
- [What Is the Linux Kernel Parameter vm.swappiness?](http://www.linuxvox.com/2009/10/what-is-the-linux-kernel-parameter-vm-swappiness/)
- [2.6 swapping behavior](http://lwn.net/Articles/83588/)
- [Understanding Virtual Memory In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4](http://people.redhat.com/nhorman/papers/rhel4_vm.pdf)
- [Understanding the Linux Kernel  3rd Ed.](http://idak.gop.edu.tr/esmeray/UnderStandingKernel.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still have one more question about distress: It seems that distress is a counter in the kernel. How can I get distress?

Comment: @Zhuo.M - yes it read that way to me as well. I've been searching for it and have yet to find it exposed under `/proc` or `/proc/sys` which leads me to believe that it isn't exposed directly. Will take a cursory look at the source which might be more revealing.

Comment: I had check the Linux 3.12 source code but I can't find anything about distress. Instead I found vmpressure, it appears that it will try to reclaim pages while alloc free pages.

Comment: @Zhuo.M - me neither. There is a VM pressure setting that you can get/set, I wonder if that's it?

Comment: I got the answer from "Understanding the Linux Kernel", distress came from prev_priority

Comment: @Zhuo.M - I added a bit at the end describing your findings, thanks.

Comment: Great! After this research, I found my question is about tuning the "Memory Management" in Linux. For Redis usage, simply put swappiness to 0 and monitor /proc/zoneinfo with "Pages free" and "Pages high" but I don't know how to re-organize my question with more preciser description. A little help, maybe?

Comment: @Zhuo.M - I would probably make that a separate Q and reference this one as a source to it. You can then self A it.